# fs::recursive_directory_iterator command doesn't iterate over sub-directories under a symbolic link

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I found that the toy implementation of `recursive_directory_iterator` furnished below doesn't iterate over sub-directories under symbolic links. So the sub-directories under a symbolic link folder are skipped. How can the issue be addressed?

```
void ScanMediaFolders()
{
    root_path = "D:\\Projects\\Media";
    for (const directory_entry& dir_entry :
        recursive_directory_iterator(root_path)){
        std::cout << dir_entry << '\n';
    }

}

int main() {
    ScanMediaFolders();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: You have a directory which contains symbolic links to other directories. And the iterator doesn't follow the symbolic links to their directories? Is that what you mean?

Comment: The iterator constructor takes an optional option argument, and one value for that is follow_symlink.

Comment: And [this `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) could be helpful to you. For us a proper [mre] and the actual versus expected output would help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: A folder containing sub-directories is mapped as a symbolic link.  The `recursive_directory_iterator` command display the soft-link but the sub-directories are skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) has (since C++17) a [constructor (number 4)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator):

```
recursive_directory_iterator(
    const std::filesystem::path& p,
    std::filesystem::directory_options options );
```

[`directory_options`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options) is an enum, and one of its entries is: `follow_directory_symlink`, which has the following meaning:

> Follow rather than skip directory symlinks.

Therefore you need to replace:

```
recursive_directory_iterator(root_path)
```

with:

```
recursive_directory_iterator(root_path, 
                     std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink)
```